ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS - Spring Security
I'm making a website with a Google login section, but I'm getting an error on the login page "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                authorizeRequests
                .requestMatchers("/", "/login**", "/css/**", 
                        "/js/**", "/images/**", "/sign-up", "/error").permitAll()                    
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html", true)
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .permitAll()
            )
            .oauth2Login(oauth2Login -> oauth2Login
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/index.html", true)
                .userInfoEndpoint(userInfoEndpoint -> userInfoEndpoint.oidcUserService(this.oidcUserService())
            )
        )
        .logout(logout -> logout.logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OidcUserService oidcUserService() {
        return new OidcUserService();
    }

I tried adding security.basic.enabled=false but it doesn't seem to work.
